# Default User Privilege of Calling Executable from Shell

Tags: vba, windows-7, vb6, uac

So, I have to fix this VB6 application `A`, which launches `B.exe` through the Shell command (`Shell(strCmd)`) along with `C.exe args` as its arguments. `B.exe` will launch `C.exe` with `args` as its arguments.

This VB6 application works under Windows XP and Windows 7 with the lowest UAC settings. However, under Windows 7 with default UAC settings (second notch from the highest), `C.exe` produces an error. When I ran `C.exe` without elevated privileges, I get the same error.

My question is:

If I ran `A` as an administrator, does `B.exe` run as an administrator if it was executed through the Shell command in `A`?

If not, what are my options without making changes to `B.exe` and `C.exe`? Without prompting the user for password in the middle of run-time if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Shell()` does not change the privilige or execution level. If an executable is running elevated then any sub processes will also be elevated.

If you want to run a process elevated from an unelevated process, you will need to use `ShellExecute()` with the `runas` verb.

It's not possibly to (directly) start a process unelevated from an elevated one.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you know if the same applies to W2KRunAsUser? Does the process invoked by that function will run as administrator by default?

Comment: I don't know what that function is. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I meant CreateProcessWithLogonW.

Comment: Looks like CreateProcessWithLogonW is the problem. Thanks.